# CalendarProvider, how to know whether an event is accepted?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I'm fetching events from the calendar and I can't find a way to know whether the event is accepted or declined.
I tried to use this column:

```
CalendarContract.Instances.STATUS
```

But it always returns 1.

How can I know that the event is declined/accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CalendarContract.Instances.SELF_ATTENDEE_STATUS.